# Emitir evento con componente hijo a componente padre Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

quiero emitir un evento de un componente hijo al padre, pero no lo consigo, adjunto código a ver si alguien le puede echar un vistazo.

route-view, se supone que es la etiqueta donde se carga el componente hijo:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <na-vue :auth="auth"></na-vue>
        </nav>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <router-view v-on:foo="hola"></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import naVue from './mains/Nav.vue';
    export default {
        components:{
            naVue
        },
        data() {
            return {
                auth:'',
            }
        },
        
        methods: {
            
            hola(){
                console.log("holaaaaa")
            }
        },
    }
    </script>
```

El boton que se supone que emite el evento al padre:

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <button @click.prevent="emitir">Porfi plis</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
    
        methods: {
            emitir(){
                this.$emit('foo');
                console.log("emitiendo");
            }
    
        },
    }
    </script>
```

Pulso el botón pero no hace nada, solo aparece el console.log("emitiendo") pero nunca se desencadena el evento en el componente padre :(((

Adjunto también el app.js por si acaso influye en algun detalle que desconozco a la hora de generarlo de esta forma:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import vue from 'vue';
window.Vue = vue;


import App from './components/App.vue';


import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';


import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes';
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router:router,
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

Comment: Estas usando un router... entonces el padre es el componente de la ruta, no main... creo que por ahi viene tu problema.. tu boton a quien le quiere avisar cosas?

Comment: Quiero avisar al componente que envuelve a los otros dos (el primer fragmento de codigo), pero he probado a poner el @foo="hola" en todas partes y no he conseguido tampoco que en ningun momento se ejecute el console.log("holaaaa")

Comment: El router se usa para mostrar un componente.. tu hijo, deberia ser hijo de algun componente que le pase los parametros para el evento.. en este caso, no va a andar nunca porquer router view no es un componente.. es quien le dice al router donde debe mostrar los componentes...

Comment: Mmm entiendo, router-view se va a sustituir por el componente que le indique el router y por tanto da igual lo que ponga ahi porque se va a borrar supongo, sabrias entonces como estructurarlo?

Comment: De todas formas ya me funciona gracias la siguiente hilo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034661/vue-js-how-can-i-emit-events-between-router-view-components

Tambien es verdad que estas cosas me pasan por lanzarme sin tener conociminetos solidos, pero voy un poco a contra tiempo

Comment: Igual todo eso esta perfectamente explicado en la documentacion de vue y de router